MERN - Vercel CORS ISSUE on Production
Using Express for Server. Facing CORS issue, using Axios at frontend with react.
This is the CORS setting.
Tried multiple settings still not able to resolve this. Not sure what wrong with settings.
  const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    const allowedOrigins = [
      "http://localhost:3000", // Development
      "https://www.abc.in",  // Production
      "https://abc.in",  // Production
      "www.abc.in"
    ];
    // Allow requests with no origin (like mobile apps or curl requests)
    if (!origin || allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
    }
  },
  credentials: true, // Allow credentials (cookies, authorization headers, etc.)
  methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS", // Allowed HTTP methods
  allowedHeaders: [
    "Content-Type",
    "Authorization",
     "x-requested-with"
  ], // Allowed headers
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options("*", cors(corsOptions)); // Preflight requests

Vercel.json
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "ekot-server",
    "builds": [
      {
         "src": "api/index.js",
         "use": "@vercel/node"
      }
   ],
   "routes": [
      {
         "src": "/(.*)",
         "dest": "api/index.js",
         "methods": ["GET","HEAD","PUT","PATCH","POST","DELETE","OPTIONS"],
         "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
         }
      }
   ]
 }

